# Can I use Bluetooth Headset for Voice Recognition In Raspberry Pi 3 B+?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3

Did somebody do voice recognition with Bluetooth Headset in Raspberry Pi 3 B+, is it Possible?

Comment: Hardward questions are off-topic on Stack Overflow. This webite is about specific *programming* questions.

Comment: To @KlausD.'s point - if your question is about Voice Recognition, then please re-format to give us an idea of what error you are encountering.

Comment: @sam If the question is *about code related* to voice recognition, then he should reform the question and add his code.

Comment: Agreed, @KlausD.  Thanks for clarifying.